# javascrip getting the value of dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I use:

```
var message = $('select.call_type option:selected').val();
```

But when I perform:

```
alert(message);
```

Then it shows a blank pop up. So, I require `call_type` value in the pop up.

Comment: what is your exact problem??

Comment: i need dropdown value in message variable

Comment: Add HTML code in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="call_type" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var message = document.getElementById("call_type").value;
  alert(message);
}
</script>
```